# why iteration loss does not match the sum of all train net output in caffe

Tags: caffe

`Iteration 1, loss = 0.0486978
Train net output #0: loss_bbox = 0.236533 (* 0.5 = 0.118266 loss)
Train net output #1: loss_cls = 0.353563 (* 0.5 = 0.176781 loss)`

Hi, i am training a CNN network using caffe, i found the iteration loss does not match the sum of all train net outputs.

any advise? thanks!

Comment: what is the display parameter in solver prototxt? what is average_loss parameter in solver prototxt?

Comment: The loss in first line is a moving average depending on average_loss parameter.It will also include loss from iteration 0.What is the loss at Iteration 0?

Comment: both the display parameter and the average_loss are 1